# How to query custom post type with 3 custom taxonomies linked to it

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm new to WordPress but I would like to know how can one get a custom post type linked to 3 custom taxonomies. I have created a custom post type called "product" and created three custom taxonomies and linked them to the product post type. My aim is to make a product have category, brand and type..which are the three custom taxonomies I have created.

[Here](http://codepad.org/opDNhZPf) is my `functions.php` file. My goal is to come up with something like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21316108/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-09%20at%206.51.43%20PM.png) where "Ved" is the category name, "Stuv" is the brand name, and "Braskaminer" is the type name of the product and lastly "stuv 16 H", "Hwam 2630" etc. are the respective products. I will really appreciate if I can get some guidance on how I can use WordPress functions to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

> When registering a post type, always register your taxonomies using
>   the taxonomies argument. If you do not, the taxonomies and post type
>   will not be recognized as connected when using filters such as
>   parse_query or pre_get_posts. This can lead to unexpected results and
>   failures.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Taxonomies

Your argument list for `register_post_type` needs to include:

```
'taxonomy' => array('ct1','ct2','ct3')
```

Your custom taxonomies *have to be* registered first.

Alternately, you can use [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type).

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'ct1', 'yourcpt' );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'ct2', 'yourcpt' );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'ct3', 'yourcpt' );
```

Again, your custom taxonomies *have to be* registered first.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I have done that but to be honest like i said am a newbie to wordpress. Do you mind guiding me on how I will fetch the products with all those taxonomy their belong to. Will really appreciate that